# Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to destroy activity : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

problem is Samsung SM G355H and micromax A106

Here is my code

```
public class EnRouteFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener{
View rootView;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ViewGroup container;
Context context;
 private GoogleMap googleMap;
 // flag for GPS status
            boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
            boolean canGetLocation = false;
            // flag for network status
            boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
            Location location; // location
            Double dblIntLat=null; // latitude
            Double dblIntLog=null; // longitude
            // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
            private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0; // 10 meters
            // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
            private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 0; // 1 minute
            // Declaring a Location Manager
            protected LocationManager locationManager;
            MarkerOptions dynamicMarker;
            Marker markerCurre;


public EnRouteFragment()
 {

 }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    this.inflater = inflater;
    this.container = container;

    initializeVariables();
    initializeUIVariables();
    initializeListeners();
    attachEventListeners();

    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void initializeVariables() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    context=getActivity();

        if (rootView != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(rootView);
        }
        try {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_enroute_marchent, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {
            /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
        }

}
@Override
public void initializeUIVariables() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void initializeListeners() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void attachEventListeners() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

// ------------------------------------fetch lat long from GPS OR NETWORK provider-------
        public Location getLocation() {
            try {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                // getting GPS status
                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                // getting network status
                isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                    // no network provider is enabled
                } else {
                    this.canGetLocation = true;
                    // First get location from Network Provider
                    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("Network", "Network");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                dblIntLat = location.getLatitude();
                                dblIntLog = location.getLongitude();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                    if (isGPSEnabled) {
                        if (location == null) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                            Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                if (location != null) {
                                    dblIntLat = location.getLatitude();
                                    dblIntLog = location.getLongitude();

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return location;
        }


        // -----------------------------------------end--------------- 

        // --------------------------------------initialize google map---------------
            private void initilizeMap() {

                if (googleMap == null) {
                    System.out.println("--------- initilizeMap() if");
                    googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.enroute_map)).getMap();
                    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
                    googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

                    if(dblIntLat!=null && dblIntLog !=null)
                    {
                        markerCurre = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                                new LatLng(dblIntLat, dblIntLog)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bike)));
                    }

                    if(dblIntLat!=null && dblIntLog !=null)
                    {
                        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(dblIntLat,dblIntLog) , 12.0f) );
                    }

                    if (googleMap == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("--------- initilizeMap() else");    

                    if(markerCurre!=null)
                    {
                        markerCurre.remove();
                    }
                    if(dblIntLat!=null && dblIntLog !=null)
                    {
                        markerCurre = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                            new LatLng(dblIntLat, dblIntLog)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bike)));
                    }
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dblIntLat = loc.getLatitude();
                dblIntLog = loc.getLongitude();

                initilizeMap();
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroyView();
    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.enroute_map);   
    if(fragment!=null)
    {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(locationManager!=null)
       {
           locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
       }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getLocation();  
}

 @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

}

here is the error log cat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3733)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3751)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3951)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:166)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1323)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1341)
       at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:597)
       at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:575)
       at com.matrix.hungerz.EnRouteFragment.onDestroyView(EnRouteFragment.java:744)
       at android.app.Fragment.performDestroyView(Fragment.java:1898)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:954)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
       at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchDestroy(FragmentManager.java:1887)
       at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:5493)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1123)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3720)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3751)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3951)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:166)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1287)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: some more log and code ??

Comment: Basically, you shouldn't make some action after some lifecycle events. Without your code I can't tell more.

Comment: Post the full error, i.e. your logcat.

Comment: plz check the log error code

Comment: Can you try moving `super.onDestroyView();` to the bottom of the `onDestroyView()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This logcat error doesn't correspond to the code you've provided.

Note this line in the logcat:

```
android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:575)
```

This means that the error was caused by a call to `FragmentTransaction.commit()`, but your code suggests that you call `FragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()`.

I can think of three possible reasons:

1. You are looking at the wrong part of the code
2. You previously had `commit()` in place of `commitAllowingStateLoss()`, and the errors happen on the older version of your app
3. Your code has been run on a custom ROM that screwed up parts of AOSP code (see below).

**The relevant parts of AOSP code:**

From `BackStackRecord`:

```
public int commit() {
    return commitInternal(false);
}

public int commitAllowingStateLoss() {
    return commitInternal(true);
}

int commitInternal(boolean allowStateLoss) {
    if (mCommitted) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("commit already called");
    }

    ...

    mManager.enqueueAction(this, allowStateLoss);
    return mIndex;
}
```

From `FragmentManagerImpl`:

```
public void enqueueAction(Runnable action, boolean allowStateLoss) {
    if (!allowStateLoss) {
        checkStateLoss();
    }

    ...
}

private void checkStateLoss() {
    if (mStateSaved) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState");
    }
    if (mNoTransactionsBecause != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Can not perform this action inside of " + mNoTransactionsBecause);
    }
}
```